# How to insert included (foreign key) field directly into the result, not referencing the table?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a `Products` table and `Photos` that belongs

```
const Photos = require('./photos.js');
const Products = require('./products.js');

Photos.belongsTo(Products, { foreignKey: 'product_ID' });
Products.hasOne(Photos, { foreignKey: 'product_ID' });

Products.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Photos,
    attributes: ["path"]
  }],
}).then(products=> {
  console.log("All data:", JSON.stringify(products, null, 4));
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
```

But I get this result (just including one element of array):

```
{
  "product_ID": 11,
  "title": "Fender Vintera 60s Jazzmaster Modified",
  "price": 1100,
  "discount": 0,
  "Photo": {
    "path": "images/guitar11.jpg"
  }
}
```

But I would like to get the `path` field directly in this JSON. Like this:

```
{
  "product_ID": 11,
  "title": "Fender Vintera 60s Jazzmaster Modified",
  "price": 1100,
  "discount": 0,
  "path": "images/guitar11.jpg"
}
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: You can try something like `attributes: { include: [[sequelize.col('Photo.path'), 'path']] }`

Comment: @Anatoly did not work if I you mean including it in place of existing attributes field. Maybe it will be even cleaner for me to leave it like it is :))

Comment: I mean to place this to main options not in include options